# Show that $\left| \mathbb{P}(X=m)-\mathbb{P}(Y=m) \right| \le \mathbb{P}(Y\ne X)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X,Y$ two random variables of the same probability space. Show that $$\left| \mathbb{P}(X=m)-\mathbb{P}(Y=m) \right| \le \mathbb{P}(Y\ne X)$$

I think I need to start from LHS and split it into probabilities where $X,Y$ equal/not equal $m$ (for example, $\mathbb{P}(X=m, Y\ne m)$).

Can you help me formalize this thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$P(X=m)=\sum_y P(X=m,Y=y)=P(X=m,Y=m)+P(X=m,Y\ne X)\\ \le P(Y=m)+P(Y\ne X)$$Similarly, $P(Y=m)\le P(X=m)+P(Y\ne X)$

Comment: The inequality is true because we're "less demanding"?

Comment: In a sense, yes. The inequality is true because $P(A)\le P(B)\ \forall A\subset B$

Comment: And how do I reach the conclusion? (I guess it's an algebraic thing)

Comment: If $a\le b+c$ and $b\le a+c$, then we get $-c\le a-b\le c\Rightarrow |a-b|\le c$

Answer (score 1):

$\left\{ X=m\right\} \subseteq\left\{ Y=m\right\} \cup\left\{ Y\neq X\right\} $
leading to: $$P\left\{ X=m\right\} \leq P\left\{ Y=m\right\} +P\left\{ Y\neq X\right\} $$

Likewise: $$P\left\{ Y=m\right\} \leq P\left\{ X=m\right\} +P\left\{ Y\neq X\right\} $$